# Cannot stop a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am very new to docker. I am following a tutorial on it.

I can successfully build and run my docker container.

```
docker build .
docker run -p 3000:3000 3cd35580990c
```

But when I try to stop the container

```
docker stop ef485ea0dabd
```

```
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: ef485ea0dabd: Cannot kill container ef485ea0dabda4939e7cc371408937174bf282a82e169c0fc71c2cf2b0b7bf74: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
```

I got this long error about permission denied.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo docker stop <id>`?

Comment: @mxmissile -- that's the image name, not the container id. The container id is ef485ea0dabd in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Your stop command is correct if you only want the container to stop. That won't remove the container though. To remove a stopped container you should use

```sh
docker container rm <id>
```

If the container is running (rather than stopped) you can force its removal using

```sh
docker container rm -f <id>
```

You can kill and remove all containers (running and stopped) using this command:

```sh
docker container rm -f $(docker ps -qa)
```

To see what containers you currently have you can use:

```sh
docker ps
```

But that only shows running containers. If you want to see stopped containers too you can do this:

```sh
docker ps -qa
```